# Changing the Diagonals of a Matrix with Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there an elegant way to change the diagonals of a matrix to a new list of values, the
equivalent of Band with SparseArray?

Say I have the following matrix (see below)

```
(mat = Array[Subscript[a, ##] &, {4, 4}]) // MatrixForm
```

and I'd like to change the main diagonal to the following to get "new mat" (see below)

```
newMainDiagList = Flatten@Array[Subscript[new, ##] &, {1, 4}]
```

I know it is easy to change the main diagonal to a given value using ReplacePart.  For example:

```
ReplacePart[mat, {i_, i_} -> 0]
```

I'd also like not to be restricted to the main diagonal (in the same way that Band is not so restricted with SparseArray)

(The method I use at the moment is the following!)

```
(Normal@SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> newMainDiagList] + 
   ReplacePart[mat, {i_, i_} -> 0]) // MatrixForm
```

(Desired Output is 'new mat')

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to use `Normal` whatsoever.  A `SparseArray` plus a "normal" matrix gives you a "normal" matrix.  Using `Band` is, on initial inspection, the most flexible approach, but an effective (and slightly less flexible) alternative is:

```
DiagonalMatrix[newDiagList] + ReplacePart[mat, {i_,i_}->0]
```

[`DiagonalMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DiagonalMatrix.html?q=DiagonalMatrix&lang=en) also accepts a second integer parameter which allows you to specify which diagonal that `newDiagList` represents with the main diagonal represented by 0.

---

The most elegant alternative, however, is to use `ReplacePart` a little more effectively:  the replacement `Rule` can be a `RuleDelayed`, e.g.

```
ReplacePart[mat, {i_,i_} :> newDiagList[[i]] ]
```

which does your replacement directly without the intermediate steps.

**Edit**: to mimic `Band`'s behavior, we can also add conditions to the pattern via [`/;`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html?q=Condition).  For instance,

```
ReplacePart[mat, {i_,j_} /; j==i+1 :> newDiagList[[i]]
```

replaces the diagonal immediately above the main one (`Band[{1,2}]`), and

```
ReplacePart[mat, {i_,i_} /; i>2 :> newDiagList[[i]]
```

would only replace the last two elements of the main diagonal in a `4x4` matrix (`Band[{3,3}]`).  But, it is much simpler using `ReplacePart` directly.

Comment: Thanks! I learned a lot from your reply.  I particularly like  ReplacePart[mat, {i_,i_} :> newDiagList[[i]] ]. I also very much like your methods to mimic Band's behaviour, which I find extremely useful (to say the least). I supppose I should have spotted DiagonalMatrix.

Comment: On unrelated topic, your username sounds like RickRoll'er.

Comment: Leonid Shifrin uses MapTherad/ReplacePart, as follows:  MapThread[ReplacePart, {mat, newMainDiagList, Range[4]}].  (See Mathematica Programming. An Advanced Introduction, by LS at www.mathprogramming-intro.org/read_online.html)

Comment: @TomD, interesting. `Timing` results shows that the `MapThread` method is 2.8 times faster, on avg, than my method. Must be due to the pattern matching. But, the `MapThread` is limited to replacing the diagonals only as `MapThread` requires each list to be the same `Length`.

Comment: Timing is not an issue for me.  I like the clarity of ReplacePart[mat, {i_,i_} :> newDiagList[[i]] ], as well as your method of mimicing Band behaviour.  After I had read your reply, I came across the LS method, and (for completeness) decided to post it.